# webkit img 100% width issues

Tags: iphone, css, webkit, overflow

[Sample Link](http://dev.dealertouch.mobi/#details)

I am using jQuery cycle to slide through these images I am having issues in iOS webkit getting the `#imagegallery` img to scale `100%` width.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found this but still can't get it working properly.

If you just google for this error, you will find plenty of people having troubles with the jQuery plugin applied to images. Troubles happens usually in terms of position and showing.

My feeling is that sometime the script is run just before the images are loaded and the used width/length values for cycling the images are wrong. I would suggest you to add something like this to your page (adapt classes and names to your needs):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $('.image-list li').each(function({$(this).css({
        [SET HERE POSITION, WIDTH, ETC]});});
      $('.image-list').cycle([OPTIONS]);
    }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: You could try wrapping the plugin-calling-code in `$(window).ready(function () { ... });`. This will wait until all images are loaded before running.